# How to change taxonomy url in node view page?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

How to change  taxonomy url in node view page in Drupal 8?

In node view page I am getting taxonomy term url pattern as term/{%term_id}. I want to change taxonomy term url to custom url in Drupal 8.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

the code below replaces term/{%term_id} by node/39?technologie={%term_id} with `THEME_preprocess_field` :

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

function MYTHEME_preprocess_field__FIELD_TAXO_MACHINE_NAME(&$variables, $hook){

    foreach ($variables['items'] as $index => $item) {

      $route_name = 'entity.node.canonical';
      $params     = 39;
      $tid = $item['content']['#options']['entity']->id();

      $options = [
        'query' => ['technologie' => $tid],
      ];

     $url = Url::fromRoute($route_name, array('node' => $params), $options);
     $variables['items'][$index]['content']['#url'] = $url;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Goto **Home -> Administration -> Structure -> Views -> Taxonomy term -> Edit** and Click **Duplicate page** and update the path with your custom path.
- Now update the existing node view's and Add **Term Id** field.
- Then update term field by clicking on it, select **Rewrite result**
  -> **Output this field as a custom link** -> Enter the link to new view's path with term id from **Replacement Patterns** and save the view. Now you will get page same default term page.